# Formik bug with re-rendering select value after changing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I use formik 2.2.9 in typescript web app and I have an issues with html select element.

So, my form has such controls:

```
export interface CriterionEdit {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    isDeleted: boolean;
    interval: number;
    groupId: number;
}
```

And I wrote such code:

```
public render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Edit</h1>

        <Formik
          enableReinitialize
          initialValues={this.props.criterion}
          onSubmit={(values) => {
            // https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/1191#issuecomment-607333552 waiting v 3.0.0
            values.interval = parseInt(values.interval as any, 10);
            values.groupId = parseInt(values.groupId as any, 10);
            values.isDeleted = (values.isDeleted as any) === "true";
            const requestOptions = {
              method: "POST",
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
              body: JSON.stringify(values),
            };
            fetch("/criterion/update/", requestOptions).then(
              () => (window.location.href = "/criteria/my")
            );
          }}
        >
          <Form translate="yes">
            <Field name="id" type="hidden" />
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="name">Criterion title</label>
              <Field name="name" className="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="interval">Interval</label>
              <Field
                name="interval"
                as="select"
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                value={this.props.criterion.interval.toString()}
                title="interval"
              >
                <option value="0">week</option>
                <option value="1">month</option>
                <option value="2">quarter</option>
                <option value="3">half-year</option>
                <option value="4">year</option>
              </Field>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="isDeleted">IsDeleted</label>
              <Field
                name="isDeleted"
                as="select"
                className="form-control"
                value={this.props.criterion.isDeleted.toString()}
                title="isDeleted"
              >
                <option value="false">no</option>
                <option value="true">yes</option>
              </Field>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="groupId">Group</label>
              <Field
                name="groupId"
                as="select"
                type="number"
                className="form-control"
                value={this.props.criterion.groupId.toString()}
                title="group"
              >
                {this.props.groups.map((option) => (
                  <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>
                    {option.title}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </Field>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
              <Field
                name="description"
                as="textarea"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Submit
            </button>
          </Form>
        </Formik>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

So, key of problem is than my select values is not strings, but html spec treats all selectboxes as elements with text values. And fomik has its own [restrictions](https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/1191#issuecomment-607333552).

Okay, I can parse exact type after selecting (using ugly 'as any'), but I can't display initial values:

when I specify `value={this.props.criterion.something.toString()}` then I have an rendering bug. I can change another value from select, it changes in internal formik values (and sends to server side properly), but doesn't re-render visual state.

And I can remove `value={this.props.criterion.something.toString()}` so my initial value (I retrieve them from api calls, that's why i use `enableReinitialize`) doesn't display correctly.

Official docs contain examples with text selectbox, no integer/boolean. So I can't understand recommended way to handle similar issues, maybe anyone already faced this? Maybe, I'm on the wrong way and I need to change my code (e.g. use 'onChange')? I've tried different types for selectbox (`type="number"` and `type="text"`) but this doesn't affect.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the different data types. Since this code is relying on the native [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement), the event value is returned as string.

So in order to match your data type, you will have to convert the string value into numbers. The same goes when selecting an Object from a collection using a select box that only uses an id and label as reference.

However, there are some issues with your implementation. The first issue is that when using Formik, you always want to use the Formik's `values`. This `values` object always contains the last value. You are now using the same value as the `initialValues` which never changes.

I think the following changes should make your code work:

1. Remove `enableReinitialize` from `<Formik />`
2. Use the Formik values instead of `this.props.criterion` for your field values
3. Serialize and Deserialize the `interval` from Formik values in the `onChange` and `value` prop

```
<Field
  as="select"
  name="interval"
  onChange={event => setFieldValue('interval', Number(event.target.value))}
  value={values.interval?.toString() || ''}
>
  <option value="0">week</option>
  <option value="1">month</option>
  <option value="2">quarter</option>
</Field>
```